# length of a string with scanf("%number[^\n], array[N].struct)

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf, sizeof

So, I have to create a program to manage a library WITHOUT USING #include

my problem is that in the function I use to add a book, I have to tell the user if he exceeded the array limit or not. What do you suggest me to do?

I decided to use `scanf(" %NUMBER[^\n], libro[i].title)`

Here's what I have so far (inside the printf's I basically ask to input authors and stuff, or I tell the user that he exceeded the limit):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int N, codice, i = 0, j = 0;
    book Library[MAXlibri];
    boolean ricerca, esito;

void InsertBook(book libro[], int i){
    printf("Inserire il titolo del libro (max 50 caratteri)\n");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", libro[i].title);
    if(sizeof(libro[i].title) > 50){
        printf("Sono stati inseriti troppi caratteri quando si inseriva il titolo del libro\n");
    }
    printf("Inserire autore o autori (max 30 caratteri)\n");
    scanf(" %29[^\n]", libro[i].auth);
    if(sizeof(libro[i].auth) > 30){
        printf("Sono stati inseriti troppi caratteri quando si inseriva l'autore\n");
    }
    printf("Inserire casa editrice (max 20 caratteri)\n");
    scanf(" %19[^\n]", libro[i].editor);
    if(sizeof(libro[i].editor) > 20){
        printf("Sono stati inseriti troppi caratteri quando si inseriva la casa editrice\n");
    }
    printf("Inserire una breve descrizione (max 50 caratteri)\n");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", libro[i].descr);
    if(sizeof(libro[i].descr) > 50){
        printf("Sono stati inseriti troppi caratteri quando si inseriva la descrizione\n");
    }
    printf("Inserire genere letterario (max 20 caratteri)\n");
    scanf(" %19[^\n]", libro[i].genre);
    if(sizeof(libro[i].genre) > 20){
        printf("Sono stati inseriti troppi caratteri quando si inseriva il genere letterario\n");
    }
    printf("Inserire codice numerico libro\n");
    scanf("%d", &libro[i].code);
    printf("Inserire anno di pubblicazione\n");
    scanf("%d", &libro[i].year);
    printf("Inserire numero pagine\n");
    scanf("%d", &libro[i].pages);
    if(sizeof(libro[i].title) < 50 && sizeof(libro[i].auth) < 30 && sizeof(libro[i].editor) < 20 && sizeof(libro[i].descr)<50 && sizeof(libro[i].genre) < 20){
        printf("Libro inserito con successo!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Il libro non e' stato inserito correttamente, riprovare\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _"without `#include`"_? You can't use `scanf` without including `stdio.h`, and your formats are probably wrong: `" %19[^\n]"` reads 19 what exactly? I take it you want `" %19[^\n]s"`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem `" %19[^\n]s"` : `s` is not required.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Right you are... still, the without `#include` bit is weird. OP is probably relying on gcc's auto-includes without realizing it. `-Wall -pedantic` flags are probably not being used here

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes, Simply just added a prototype without to the `#include`.
 it is possible that it does not work as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

sample test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char buff[10+1];
    char ch = 0;
    int len;
    while(1){
        printf("input max 10 characer(type '.' for exit)\n");
        scanf(" %10[^\n]%c", buff, &ch);
        if(*buff == '.')
            break;
        len = strlen(buff);
        printf("i received : '%s'\n", buff);
        printf("input length : %d\n", len);
        if(ch != '\n'){//Input is greater than in the case where a newline is not set
            printf("you typed greater than 10 character\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n')
                ;//drop upto newline
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few problems here:
First and most importantly you might want to rethink how you manage memory for the books in the library. It's a very bad idea to allow a max number of characters for titles, authors etc..You will run into serious limitations down the line.

For this I suggest you use strings which make things a bit easier as the memory allocation is transparent - you can resize, clear, delete them without worrying too much about memory.
If you, insist on using byte arrays (i.e char[N]) you can do so, but you should allocate the memory dynamically. This will allow you to have any length for your fields and won't waste memory.

By looking at the core, I suspect you are using statically allocated buffers. I really hope you did not allocated them on the stack because that is the worst possible place for them. If you insist on having them statically allocated they should be declared globally so at least the go in the .data section

And back to your initial Question, how to get the length, you can use scanf("%s\n"), and strlen afterwards.

To read the strings you can use whichever function you want as long as you consider the limitations: fgets stops on '\n' or EOF. This might be a problem if you have a title on two lines for example). scanf on the other hand reads formated text sou you would have to be careful that your text is all formated the same way.

Hope this helps